# How does Reactive Extension Operator SkipLast work?

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx-java2

In Reactivex.IO documentation it was stated that

> You can ignore the final n items emitted by an Observable and attend only to those items that come before them, by modifying the Observable with the SkipLast operator.

and the diagram from http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/skiplast.html
[image]

My Expectations: SkipLast will read the entire Observable till it meets the OnCompleted and then generates a new Observable with the timings as the Original one but skipping the Last ones.

My Doubt: How does SkipLast Operator know that "3" is that Last 2nd Item from the Observable? Without seeing the OnCompleted how can it tell the Last nth Item?

Comment: The observable only has to cache `n` items to know whether it reached the end and what to discard. It doesn't have to consume all events before emitting, it can cache `n` items and emit the oldest one when a new one arrives. When `Complete()` arrives, it can discard the cached items and complete itself

Comment: In this case it could cache `1` and `2` until `3` arrives, at which point it emits `1`. When `4` arrives, it emits `4`. When `Complete` arrives it discards `3` and `4` and completes. In fact, the diagram shows that `1` is emitted at the same time `3` arrives

Comment: How does the observable know that it has to emit cached value 1 when it reaches 3?

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/observable/ObservableSkipLast.java#L68) is straightforward.

Comment: @PKChem what do you mean? It's not difficult, it only needs to check how big its buffer is.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks I got it, its like a Queue with fixed size. Enqueue the items and when dequeue happens because of overflow then it OnNext that dequeued value.

Comment: @PKChem if you check akarnokd's link to the source you'll see that the operator *is* an actual ArrayDequeue that implements Observable

Comment: @PKChem - Please don't edit your question with the solution. Add your solution as an answer and then accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, @akarnokd for Valuable comments.

It is internally implemented with a Queue of Fixed Size. Take the items from the Sequence and Enqueue them, when the Queue is full and Starts to Overflow Dequeue the item & Enqueue the latest value and Send to OnNext(dequeued_value), so when OnCompleted Reached you will not Send the Cached items and just call OnCompleted. By this last N cached items are Skipped.

Answer (score 0):

From a [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/skipLast.ts#L78) if `skipLast(N)` is used, then `N` messages is kept in the `this._ring` array. As soon N+1 arrived first message is emitted, N+2 arrived => second messages is emitted etc.